# Thread-safety of this design?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I've inherited some C# code to maintain and I have some reservations about the design, but I don't know if I should.   This is for a C# application that controls some industrial processes.

We have a method *DoCertify()* which fires off a worker thread to control a sequence of industrial processes.   In each step of the sequence it controls some machinery then compiles some data.

The caller, in the UI thread, allocates an array of objects representing these steps and calls *DoCertify()* passing the array as a **ref** variable.
Periodically as each step in the sequence is done, *DoCertify()*'s worker thread fills in the data in the associated element of the array (step 0, element0, step 1, element 1, etc), and invokes a delegate (i.e., a callback to the UI thread) announcing that step is done, and then it continues to the next step.

When the callback in the UI thread is called, it reads and displays the data in the just-finished element of the array.  In this manner, as *DoCertify()* runs its progress can be updated on the display.

There's no explicit thread-safety built into this but the code's writer says that it's inherently safe because once the worker thread writes to an element and signals that it's done, it will never write to that element again, so there's no danger of the worker thread and UI thread trying to access the same element in the array at the same time.

Does that provide sufficient thread safety or should more explicit thread-safety be build in to this design?

Comment: I'll vote to close this question as too broad but here's what I think. If it's _guaranteed_ that the array is around for the entire duration of the worker thread with a fixed size and each element is only written by the worker thread _before_ calling the deletegate _and_ the element is only read by the UI thread _after_ the delegate then it's safe.

Comment: As long as there's no possibility of a series of reads and writes (1 write in worker thread -> delegate call -> 1 read in UI thread in that strict order) this is a safe approach. This is educated speculation, though - the actual implementation may do something that looks safe but isn't.

Comment: @xxbbcc  What would make it less "broad"?   I could give code samples but it would be hundreds of lines of fairly dense code, which I'd have to obfuscate anyway because it's proprietary.  I'm open to suggestions on how to make it less "broad".

Comment: That's exactly what makes it too broad. :)  It's not a bad question but it's also impossible to answer without speculation and without seeing all that code.

Comment: If your code is that complicated, you should spend some time analyzing it - if it's supposed to be the `1 write -> notify -> 1 read` pattern then the code related to _that_ should be pretty simple and easy to locate. If it's not, it's worth looking into, especially if you have random errors coming from this area of the application. Thread-safety issues are hard to track down.

Comment: If you have a worker that needs to update the UI with its current progress just use a tool that's specifically designed to do exactly that, and that will handle all of the synchronization for you, such as the `Progress` class.  Then you just don't need to think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's thread-safe, but not safe-safe. By that I mean *if* what you say is true that the caller doesn't read anything until the callee calls the callback, and the caller doesn't modify the original data after handoff to the the worker, etc -- you're fine.

But it's not safe-safe because a developer might easily do something in the future like try to reuse the array between calls, add a value to the array, change one, or otherwise take advantage of the **ref** thinking they can use the values in the same scope. Who knows.

The design you describe *can't* prevent misbehavior on either end. A design that works on a copy of the array (and copies of the array elements) is a better bet.